not receiving data from zabbix agent
Good Morning,
I have a problem is that I have various hosts which, even having the zabbix agent installed, zabbix proxy confiugred and the ports 10050-10051 opened on the firewall of the operating system I get the same error Zabbix agent is not available:

But once I do hover over the error in some cases I get the following error:
Get value from agent failed: cannot connect to [[IP ADDRESS OF THE COMPUTER]:10050]: [111] Connection refused

Whereas on other I get this one:
Get value from agent failed: cannot connect to [[IP ADDRESS OF THE COMPUTER]:10050]: [4] Interrupted system call

What's the difference between both errors?¿What can we check in order to solve it?
Thank you very much

the service which should listen on 10050 is not running imho

connection refused indicates that the zabbix agent is not running. Or you are using the wrong IP address, or the wrong port.

Could be a certificate issue. If you use Active agent to zabbix server (port 10051) do you get metrics? I usually stay away from using IPs and stick to FQDN

Interrupted System Call is usually returned when the server name verification fails. IIRC, in Zabbix Agent you need to set the IP/Hostname of the server, the proxy in your situation. If the proxy/server IP doesn't match the one set in the agent's configuration, the agent drops the connection with this error.
Connection Refused is 99% a firewall problem. If you're 100% sure the firewall on the Zabbix hosts is open (you should try a telnet from the network, to be 100% sure), then there's something between your proxy and the agents blocking the connection. Maybe an outgoing firewall rule on the proxy itself?
Generally speaking, your question is not detailed enough to give more specific answers.
